# How to strip the last part of a query string

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof

I need to isolate an id in a string using javascript. I've managed to get to the part where I get to the id but then I want to be able to string the rest of the string so that it only leaves the id number such as this:

```
  var urlString = "http://mysite.co.za/wine/wine-blog/blogid/24/parentblogid/15.aspx";


    // if the blogid is found in the url string

    if (urlString.indexOf("blogid") != -1) {
        alert("blogid id found");

        // we strip the string to isolate the blogid

        url = urlString.substring(urlString.indexOf("blogid") + 7);

        //alert("url : " + url)
        blogId = url.substring(0, urlString.indexOf("/"));

        alert("blogId : " + blogId)
    }
```

I need to be able to strip everything after the 24.

Thanks all.

Comment: have you tried spliting the string with "/" delimiter? try using string.split("/")  and use the array operation for rest u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tempString = urlString.Split("blogid")[1];
var blogIdStr = tempString.Split("/")[1];
```

for the integer:

```
var blogId = parseInt(blogIdStr);
```

[edit:]
long form would be:

```
var tempArray = urlString.Split("blogid");
// try:
// alert(tempArray, tempArray.length);
var tempString = tempArray[1];
(...)
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding me! :)
Thanks Martin!

Comment: edited my answer for better understanding. ^^
@other answers: I agree on the power of regexp, though for regexp-inexperienced programmers (like me), the above is far more readable and can directly be traced.
Also, when debugging you'll see that the string "blogid" appears twice, thus creating a tempArray with 3 fields. Talk about greedy or not searches.

Comment: you should always use parseInt(x, 10) if you expect the number to be decimal, otherwise you could end up in hex/oct.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will keep that one for another rainy day! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var blogIdStr = urlString.replace(/(.*\/blogid\/\d+).*/, "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare cases where a regexp is both simpler and easier to understand:

```
var matches = urlString.match(/\/blogid\/(\d+)\//);
if (matches) {
    var id = matches[1];
}
```

or, if you're not worried about errors:

```
var id = urlString.match(/\/blogid\/(\d+)\//)[1];
```